# OnDissmissListener and OnCancelListener not executing when tapping outside custom dialog in Java for Android

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have a custom dialog which when the user exits out of it, the main activity is to be refreshed by using start activity. So far this is not the case as the dialog closes without either of the listeners executing. This occurs when pressing the back button as well as pressing off the dialog on the screen.

```
public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {

public Activity mActivity; 

public CustomDialogClass(Activity activity) {
    super(activity);
    this.mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

    setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

    new OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("check", "STARTED_dismiss");
            Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, MainActivity.class);
            mActivity.startActivity(i);

        }
    };

    new OnCancelListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("check", "STARTED_Cancel");
            Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, MainActivity.class);
            mActivity.startActivity(i);
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: But where do you set those listeners to the dialog? I can see that you  just create anonymous objects(the listeners) but you don't do anything with they.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the listeners, in order to do that just call the **setOnDismissListener** and **setOnCancelListener** methods in the onCreate method. Like this:

```
setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
       // your code here
   }
});

setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
       // your code here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You create anonymous listener. You need to handle youre listener.
do something like this:

```
OnDismissListener onDismissListener = new OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("check", "STARTED_dismiss");
        Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, MainActivity.class);
        mActivity.startActivity(i);

    }
};

OnCancelListener onCancelListener = new OnCancelListener(){

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("check", "STARTED_Cancel");
        Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, MainActivity.class);
        mActivity.startActivity(i);
    }

};
```

and then add listeners to your object:

```
myObject.setOnDismissListener(onDismissListener);
myObject.setOnCancelListener(onCancelListener);
```